# Passing a struct to a constructor in MQL4

Tags: mql4, mql5

Passing each individual args into a constructor when you have 10 or more is tedious and not very maintainable - also makes reading the constructor args quite a drag.

The pattern I want to use is commonly used in Ruby/Node/Python and was hoping there was something similar in MQL4

So I want to pass a key value pair object to the constructor with all the args. 
Unfortunately I am getting -

```
struct cannot be defined in param list.
```

from the compiler.

I am a total n00b at C and this is my first MetaQuotes4 programme(EA) attempt. I have Googled and trawled the docs. Can't find a thing besides the docs saying that passing classes, arrays and structs can only be done using pass by reference.

The issue is line 10.

[image: Screen shot]

it's loaded with compile errors - due to this being a WIP.  The rest of the errors I can handle but the struct not allowed in params issue has me baffled. Any help or advice would be awesome.

Maybe there is an alternative pattern?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don't post images of text. Instead please edit your question to include the faulty code *as text* as well as the complete and unedited error output *as text*.

Comment: Apologies - essential this was a amateurs attempt, and as @user3666197 I seemed to have missed quite  a bit in the documentation.

Comment: I got the same anwser as the one @Bo Pearson suggested on the actuual mql4 forum - but still to no avail. 

Mql4 documentation is not fun.
Thanks again fellow programmers.

Comment: Welcome to the MQL4-world. The best hit ever made was a "silent" change of the MQL4-language syntax near about the Build-572++. The whole code-base had to be re-programmed due to ***"new"***-MQL4 ( MQL4.5678 and the syntax creep continues ... ) restrictions regarding variable validity scope changed, forbidden literals in names of variables. Nightmare indeed once your code-base has about a few hundreds man*years. And creeping ...

Answer (score 2):

### Be carefull - `MQL4` is in many aspects not alike a `C++` compiler

While syntax constructors may look similar, real use is restricted or forbidden in `.MQL4` compilation by a **`MetaLang.exe`** compiler.

So, **`struct`** look promising, **but will not fit your wish.**

As depicted in your print-screen,

```
...
string symbol = params.symbol;
...
```

you plan to include also **`string`** typed values in you `struct`.

While this is possible, the **`MQL4` documentation** however implicates restrictions for such **`struct`** usage and the only form of `struct`, that is permitted to be safely used in function call parameter passing is just a **SIMPLE STRUCT**, i.e. a `struct` without any string component ( after many years spent in `MQL4` domain, you would have been ***prepared*** for similar ***specialities***. Some of which include a `string` which is internally not a `string`, but a `struct` and the nightmare has just started ... ( and you can imagine, what that implodes on your DLL-interfacing et al. ).

> The structure name **can't** be used as an identifier (name of a variable or function).

or

> It should be noted that in MQL4 structure elements follow one another **directly, without alignment**.
> In C++ such an order is made to the compiler using the following instruction:
> `#pragma pack(1)`
>   If you want to do another alignment in the structure, use auxiliary members, "fillers" to the right size.

and

> With  the **`return`** operator you **can't** return any arrays, class objects, variables of compound structure type.

**So be carefull and read MQL4 Documentation start-to-end, as some "specialities" are hidden in places, one would hardly expect them a-priori.**

Answer (score 1):

You can pass it to the constructor like `const StructDef &_var_name`, for example:

```
class Order {

  // Define struct.
  struct Params {
    string symbol;
    double market_entry;
    double loss_pips;
    double profit_pips;
  };
  // Struct class variable.
  Params params;

  public:
  Order(const Params &_params) {
    this.params = _params;
  };

}
```

Then use it like:

```
Params params = {_Symbol, Ask};
// or...
params.symbol = _Symbol;
params.market_entry = Ask;
// ... then:
Order *order = new Order(params);
```

See: [Structures, Classes and Interfaces](https://docs.mql4.com/basis/types/classes).